# Initializing <random> classes in constructor causes segfault

Tags: c++, c++11, random

In the code below, `RandomCharSource` is supposed to simply return a random character upon request. Its constructor is initializing an `mt19937`, `uniform_int_distribution<int>` and a `random_device`. However, when I instantiate my object, I get a segfault.

When I create these random classes manually in the `bar()` function below, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong? Is there an initialization order issue here? I'm using GCC 4.7.3.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

class RandomCharSource
{
public:
    explicit RandomCharSource() : _re{_rd()}, _dist{0, 255} {};
    inline char get_next_char() { return _dist(_re); };
private:
    std::mt19937 _re;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> _dist;
    std::random_device _rd;
};

void foo()
{
    RandomCharSource s;
    std::cout << s.get_next_char() << std::endl;
}

void bar()
{
    std::random_device _rd;
    std::mt19937 _re{_rd()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> _dist{0,255};
    std::cout << (char)_dist(_re) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    bar(); // Works OK
    foo(); // Segfault

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because of your initialization order

```
class RandomCharSource
{
public:
    explicit RandomCharSource() : _re{_rd()}, _dist{0, 255} {};
    inline char get_next_char() { return _dist(_re); };
private:
    std::mt19937 _re;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> _dist;
    std::random_device _rd;
};
```

You need to have `_rd` before `_re`. The members are initialized in the order they are declared in the class. So when you try to initialize `_re` using `_rd`, `_rd` hasn't yet been initialized.

From the standard `§12.6.2.13` (emphasis mine)

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> 13.1 — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class base-specifier-list.
> 13.2 — Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
> 13.3 — Then, **non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition** (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).
> 13.4 — Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed.
> [Note: The declaration order is mandated to ensure that base and member subobjects are destroyed in the
> reverse order of initialization. —end note]